# How to generate DbSet dynamically in .net core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I use generic repository and I want to use dbcontext without declaration of dbset for each single database model. I tried some solutions but every time I've got this error :

> Cannot create a DbSet for 'PointsType' because this type is not
> included in the model for the context.

```
public new DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
  return base.Set<TEntity>();
}
```

BaseEntity used for generic repository.

Is there anyway to solve this problem ?

Comment: That was added to entity folder in which other entities were placed. In fact, in the same assembly of my DbContext. @GertArnold I got the answer . Thank you anyway.

Comment: Next time please try to imagine which information is relevant when asking a question. Also, if the answer helped you, please mark it as accepted, so we see that the question has been dealt with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **have to** register entities in a DbContext. It can infer relations and discover other entities by itself, but it's better to be explicit about it.

You have two options:

### 1. Adding `DbSet<T>` properties to DbContext

One way to do this is to add `DbSet<TEntity>` properties in DbContext class:

```cs
class AppDbContext: DbContext {
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

This is easy, but requires modifying DbContext for every new entity.

### 2. Implementing `IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>`

Another way is to implement `IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>` for all entities, and let DbContext discover configurations using `modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly` method.

Note that there are no `DbSet<TEntity>` properties in the DbContext class!

```cs
class AppDbContext: DbContext
{
    // no DbSet properties 

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(AppDbContext).Assembly);
    }
}

class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

class ProductEntityConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Product> builder)
    {
        builder.HasIndex(e => e.Title).IsUnique();
    }
}
```

Now you can access a DbSet for an entity using:

```cs
var productSet = dbContext.Set<Product>();
```

### References

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/#grouping-configuration